# Unable to save video recorded file with SurfaceView camera in android

Tags: java, android

I am able to record video file but not able to save video recorded file in phone memory. So please any one help me to to save recorded video file in phone memory. I am new in android please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String VIDEO_PATH_NAME = "/sdcard/default.mp4";
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private View mToggleButton;
    private boolean mInitSuccesful;
    private File fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleRecordingButton);
        mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            // toggle video recording
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()) {
                    mMediaRecorder.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finish();
                } else {
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                    mMediaRecorder.reset();
                    try {
                        initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.unlock();
        }
        if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mInitSuccesful = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (!mInitSuccesful)
                initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    private void shutdown() {
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mCamera.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        mCamera = null;
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        Log.d("Media Store Directory", "" + mediaStorageDir);
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            Log.d("Video file", "" + mediaFile);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleRecordingButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Start Recording"
        android:textOn="Stop Recording" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></SurfaceView>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the path you've used to save the file is incorrect

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
```

Try:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"videocapture_example.mp4");
```

This method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` doesn't necessarily return the path to the SD card. [Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) you can find more details about that.